# CryptographicException on SignedCms.Decode

Tags: .net, security, cryptography, pkcs#7, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a function that read content of signed file (eg. [MYFILE].xml.p7m) by this code:

```
 Dim signedCms As New SignedCms()

 signedCms.Decode([MYFILEBYTES])

 Dim content As Byte() = signedCms.ContentInfo.Content
```

Unfortunately I need to run this program on an old "Windows Server 2003 R2" system, but it generate this exception:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Stack:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.OpenToDecode(Byte[], 
      System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo, Boolean)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.Decode(Byte[])
```

with message "Unknown cryptographic algorithm".

On another "Windows Server 2003 R2" machine, it works correctly.

My question is: what component should I install on "Windows Server 2003 R2" for the signedCms.Decode statement to work correctly?

Comment: That suggests that a non-standard signature algorithm, or non-standard digest algorithm, is indicated within the payload (you'd need to be able to provide an example for any other help).  If that "non-standard" algorithm is SHA-2 then you probably need the specific patches listed on https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pki/2010/09/30/sha2-and-windows/.  And to upgrade to an OS that hasn't been out of support for more than 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion...I have found this post https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/security-updates/securitybulletins/2013/ms13-095 and installed os patch for Windows Server 2003. It works!